# How to allocate memory to an pointer passed to a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(int *newvar);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int *var;
    func(var);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void func(int *newvar)
{
    int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    newvar = tmp;
}
```

After the function has exited, a value of the pointer 'var' did not change. What could be wrong in my code?

Comment: your pointer is passed by value.

Comment: Thanks, I think I missed it. I need to pass pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Yes, exactly so

Comment: There is no such thing as allocating memory to a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*After the function has exited, a value of the pointer 'var' did not change* ? if you want var to be changed then pass the `address` of `var` and in `func()` catch with `double pointer` as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int *var;
        printf("before in %s : %p\n",__func__,var);
        func(&var); /* pass the address of var */
        printf("after in  %s : %p\n",__func__,var);
        //system("pause");
        return 0;
}

void func(int **newvar) {
        int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*newvar));
        *newvar = tmp; /* it will change the var in calling function */
        printf(" in  %s : %p\n",__func__,*newvar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the memory location of var to func like this

```
func(&var);
```

Comment: You'd also have to change the function parameter `void func(int **newvar)`